# Dynect API permissions needed to delete a CNAME

Tags: dns-hosting, dyndns

I'm trying to create a `Dynect` managed dns user with the minimum set of permissions necessary to add and delete CNAMEs via the REST API.

So far I can create `CNAMEs` but not delete them.

I have `RecordAdd`, `RecordUpdate`, `RecordDelete`, `ZoneAddNode`, `ZoneRemoveNode`, and `ZonePublish` set.

- When I try to delete a CNAME via the API I get a `404` error with *"Host is not in this zone"*.
- When I try to delete the `CNAME` in the same way with a fully-privileged user it works fine, so I know the API call is correct.

Comment: Solved this - You also need the RecordGet permission in addition to RecordAdd/Update/Delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need the RecordGet permission in addition to RecordAdd/Update/Delete.